# antisamy does not encode @

Tags: xss, antisamy

I am using antisamy 1.5 to prevent XSS.

I saw issue when input was

```
firstname,lastname<name@mail.com> or firstname,lastname<name@mail.com testing>
```

Result after Antisamy scan is same for both above case

```
firstname,lastname<name>
```

I have below directive in policy file

```
<directive name="onUnknownTag" value="encode"/>
```

Is there a place in policy file I can update to encode @ ?

Comment: you need to add custom rule in policy file. which policy file you are using now?